# Subscribe to and process change to multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to add an event listener to input elements with element id's I have stored in a list and then take the product of them.  For example:

```
a = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

I would like to do something like:

```
input element id1 = 0.5
input element id2 = 0.6
input element id3 = 1.0
return 0.5*0.6*1
```

and I would like this to update as the user changes the values in the input box.

So I have started with something like:

```
function calcProduct(values){
    var product = 1;
    for(i=0; values.length; i++){
        product = product*values[i];
    }
    return product
}

id_list = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
function calcProduct(id_list){
    for(i=0; id_list.length; i++){
        //how do I get the values as they change so I can feed it to calcProduct?
        document.getElementById(id_list[i]).addEventListener("onchange", calcProduct(values) )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an event listener and `reduce()` you can accumulate the final product. Note: in an event listener, omit the 'on', so use `change` rather than `onchange`. To make it easier, I used a className for inputs that will be calculated

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.to-calc').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', calcProduct))
  calcProduct()
})

function calcProduct(e) {
  let output = [...document.querySelectorAll('.to-calc')].reduce((b, a) => b * +a.value, 1)
  console.log(output.toFixed(2))
  return output.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input class='to-calc' type='number' value='0.5'> <input class='to-calc' type='number' value='0.6'> <input class='to-calc' type='number' value='0.1'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would combine event delegation and reactive programming for this.

Attach your event listener to a parent node and filter the events as they come in:

1. When an `input` event is dispatched the parent `<div>` catches it.
2. The `filter` operator makes sure we consume the right events.
3. The `scan` operator writes new values to the map.
4. The `map` operator multiplies the values in the map.
5. Finally the subscriber receives and displays the product.

This way we can work with multiple sets of numbers.
*(Note how the map corresponds to ids and values in the DOM.)*

```js
const mult = nums =>
  fromEvent(document.querySelector('div'), 'input')                       //1
  .pipe( filter(e => e.target.id in nums)                                 //2
       , scan((acc, {target: {id, value}}) => (acc[id]=value, acc), nums) //3
       , map(ns => Object.values(ns).reduce((p, n) => p * n, 1)));        //4

mult({n1: 1, n2: 1, n3: 1}).subscribe(display('#p1'));                    //5
mult({n4: 1, n5: 1, n6: 1}).subscribe(display('#p2'));                    //5
mult({n7: 1, n8: 1, n9: 1}).subscribe(display('#p3'));                    //5
```

```css
input{width:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlqMFvHwgWJ1vfts5fdC2WzxDaIXWfYuAd9Tb2lobtF61Gk+HIRDrbtxgasBSM9lZgOK9ilwK9LqFIYEV+k0IA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const {fromEvent} = rxjs;
const {filter, map, scan} = rxjs.operators;
const display = sel => val => document.querySelector(sel).textContent = val;
</script>
<div>
  <input id="n1" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n2" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n3" type="number" value="1"/> = <span id="p1">1</span>
  <hr/>
  <input id="n4" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n5" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n6" type="number" value="1"/> = <span id="p2">1</span>
  <hr/>
  <input id="n7" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n8" type="number" value="1"/> ×
  <input id="n9" type="number" value="1"/> = <span id="p3">1</span>
</div>
```